# Ajax Response Json Print result in table or div array

Tags: php, ajax, json, jquery

I have an ajax call to a php file that encodes the array into a json array/object. What I am trying to do is to print the json response into a table format or an array of
 div's. I am stuck on how to handle the response on ajax success. Here is my ajax..

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#adapter").keyup(function()
        {
            var adapter = $(this).val();
            var dataString = 'searchword='+ adapter +'&format=json' ;
            if(adapter=='' || adapter < 2 )
            {
                $("#display3").hide('');        
            }
            else
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax/phpfile",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(data) 
                    {
                        var myObj = data;
                        ///NOT how to print the result and decode in html or php///
                    }
                });
            }return false; 
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the json response back from the server. I can alert the whole json response, so I know it is working on the ajax side...

```
{"Result":[{"ptos":{"PTOMasterID":"1","PTOMasterPart":"828B-U6805-L1CX","PTOSeriesUniqueID":"22","PTOPrice":"2715.78","PTOSeries":"82","PTOMounting":"8B","PTOTransmission":"U68","PTOSpeed":"05","PTOShifter":"L","PTOAssemblyID":"1","PTOShaftID":"C","PTOSpecialFeature":"X","PTODate":"2011-11-30 17:28:10"}},{"ptos":{"PTOMasterID":"2","PTOMasterPart":"828B-U6805-L3CX","PTOSeriesUniqueID":"22","PTOPrice":"2715.78","PTOSeries":"82","PTOMounting":"8B","PTOTransmission":"U68","PTOSpeed":"05","PTOShifter":"L","PTOAssemblyID":"3","PTOShaftID":"C","PTOSpecialFeature":"X","PTODate":"2011-11-30 17:28:10"}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#adapter").keyup(function()
    {
        var adapter = $(this).val();
        var dataString = 'searchword='+ adapter +'&format=json' ;
        if(adapter=='' || adapter < 2 )
        {
            $("#display3").hide('');        
        }
        else
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json", //set this to json
                url: "ajax/phpfile",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) 
                {
                    var myObj = data;
                    ///NOT how to print the result and decode in html or php///
                    console.log(myObj); //to see the object
                }
            });
        }return false; 
    });
});
```

Alternatively you could use JSON2.js like so

```
JSON.parse(text, reviver)
```

[JSON 2 GITHUB](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)

Comment: How would you use this JSON.parse(text, reviver)? Am I going to place this in the ajax response success function? Also, when I declare the dataType as Json and try to alert the repsonse back from the server, I get nothing. It just says [object Object] in the alert box. Before, without the declaration I retrieved the whole repsonse.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a `dataType: "JSON"` if you're going to return JSON data from an ajax call.  Then it's just `var pto_id = data.ptos.PTOMasterID` and you can do a `$(object).html(pto_id);` to put in the value.  Hope that answers the questions you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question-- I found this online. It should be able to iterate over all the objects and all the properties of the objects.

http://www.openjs.com/scripts/others/dump_function_php_print_r.php